# How to localize the route action/controller in .NET Core

Tags: url, .net-core, localization, internationalization

Searched but can't find any question specifically about localizing controller/actions rather than just adding the culture itself to URL.

I have a localized .NET Core website, by inserting /es/ into the URL (before controller/action is the way its set up i.e. www.bla.com/es/account/profile).

This uses culture settings and saves the culture in a cookie, and the site uses IStringLocalizer and it all works well.

My problem is, I now need to translate the route itself.

```
www.bla.com/account/profile
```

OR

```
www.bla.com/es/cuenta/perfil
```

*(google translate just for example)*

I don't think I am worried about translating any query strings or variable names at the moment, just the action and controller names themselves.

Comment: You could add a custom middleware to rewrite the url from the custom language to English before the Mvc middlewares.

Answer (score 1):

To add a middleware to rewrite the url, add this into your `Startup.Configure` method before `UseRouting`, `UseRoute`, or `UseMvc` depending on what is currently used:

```
//This definition should be moved as a field or property.
//And the value should be loaded dynamically.
var urlMappings = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "/es/cuenta/perfil", "/account/profile" },
    // others
};

//Rewriting the matched urls.
app.Use(next => http =>
{
    if (urlMappings.TryGetValue(http.Request.Path.Value, out var result))
    {
        http.Request.Path = new PathString(result);
    }
    return next(http);
});
```

This is just an example on how to implement it, though url mapping rule should be managed within services.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by "though url mapping dire" - this looks kind of clean so ill give it a try - but will this display the correct URL in the browser still or overwrite it with the english? Also, when I redirect to another page from a controller action, how do I ensure the correct URL is displayed to the user?

Comment: Ah sorry, just few words missing. Does this work for you?

Comment: well the bit I am confused with is "when I redirect to another page from a controller action, how do I ensure the correct URL is displayed to the user?"

Comment: It is technically not redirecting, but rewriting the path value that is going to be handled by ASP.NET Core's routing middleware, so the url displayed to the user is never changed.

Comment: As for redirection in controllers, you can simply add a scoped service that has a locale indecator property as `enum` or `string` to the container, and within this middleware, you resolve the service and set the locale indecator to a proper value extracted from the url. Then resolve the service in the controller to indicate which language to redirect.